# How do recover video lost after undoing copy operation?

Tags: ios, windows, recovery, data

I had shot some video clips using my phone which I "cut and pasted" in a new folder on my desktop (windows). By mistake, I pressed the Ctrl + Z button which undid the action when the phone was still connected, I opened my phone but couldn't find those video, so I did "Ctrl + z" again, hoping to undo the previous action which actually worked but only bright back an empty folder, no video clips inside. I've tried using **wondershare recoveryit**, **Dr phone**, **mini too power data recovery**, I couldn't find my files, I even thought of recovering lost data from my phone but could only find **deleted** videos instead. This was a very important project and I feel I let the whole team down, I really really need help.

Comment: Did you check the Trash on Windows?

Comment: I'm afraid cut & paste on Windows is a really 'dangerous' operation to interrupt [macOS has no cut operation at all, which is much safer]. In future use copy/paste & delete manually after successful transfer. The files *might* still be there, though possibly hidden. iMyPhone has a good walkthrough [which I cannot test, don't have Windows]. They do, of course, want to sell you their software, but they provide alternative methods - https://www.imyfone.com/data-recovery/how-to-recover-files-lost-during-cut-and-paste/